# RWD Mobile Device Image Swap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, getelementbyid, onmouseover

I am using a bit of JavaScript to do an image swap.

Works great on desktop browsers, but not working on mobile/smaller devices.

```
<p><img id="ima" src="images/web_assets/image1.jpg" width="270px" />
</p>
<p><a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'images/web_assets/image1.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image1.jpg" width="84px" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'images/web_assets/image2.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image2.jpg" width="84px" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'images/web_assets/image3.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image3.jpg" width="84px" /></a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function showT(image) {
        document.getElementById('ima').setAttribute('src', image)
    }
    // ]]>

</script>
```

Any idea's how to make this work on all devices (i.e. desktop, ipads, iphones, other mobile devices)?

**New Code:**

```
<p><img id="ima" src="images/web_assets/image1.jpg" width="270px" />
</p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="showT( 'images/web_assets/image1.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image1.jpg" width="84px" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="showT( 'images/web_assets/image2.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image2.jpg" width="84px" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="showT( 'images/web_assets/image3.jpg' )"><img src="images/web_assets/image3.jpg" width="84px" /></a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function showT(image) {
        document.getElementById('ima').setAttribute('src', image)
    }
    // ]]>

</script>
```

But onclick, it shoots the page back upto the top of the browser?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The 'onmouseover' event isn't really the best choice to make something working cross device, because you simply don't have a mouse on mobile, tablets.

Maybe think about making it working on the click event for mouseless devices ?

Comment: Thanks... do you have an example? (not really a JS guy)

Comment: I have changed to onClick (as above edited) but when clicking on an image it swaps the image, but also shoots the page back to the top of the browser - any way to stop this?

Comment: top, please validate this answer to close the topic :)